# Mobile Web App URL does not match Worklight Development Server host name (IP)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Using Worklight Studio 6.1.0.1 and Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7, I am seeing an inconsistency with the Worklight Development Server host IP. I have changed the host name from localhost to the IP address I want to use. That IP address is being used when I open the Worklight Console. However, my application includes a Mobile Web application and when I click its "Get App URL" link in the Worklight Console it displays a link using a different IP address. I have several network adapters that have IP addresses - my wired LAN adapter (which has the IP I want to use), my VPN adapter and an adapter configured by VirtualBox. If I am connected to the VPN, the app URL uses the IP address for the VPN adapter. If I am not connected to the VPN, the app URL uses the IP address for the VirtualBox adapter (which is a 169.254.x.x address). In neither case does it use the IP address for my wired adapter. I have modified the Windows Network Connections Advanced Settings so that the wired adapter takes precedence over the VPN adapter which takes precedence over the VirtualBox adapter.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? This makes the app URL difficult to use since my device cannot access either of those IP addresses. The best I can do is scan the QR code then manually change the IP address on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the URL used for the Mobile Web envrionment's "Get App URL" in preview:

1. Open your-project\server\conf\worklight.properties
2. Uncomment the `publicWorkLightHostname` property
3. Provide a host or IP address
4. Re-deploy the application
5. Load Worklight Console and click on "Get App URL"

The URL should now point to the address from step 3 above.